# pyttsx3 разные голоса

Tags: python, pyttsx3

У меня есть интересный вопрос. Возможно ли использовать голоса знаменитостей в pyttsx3(ну, например голос Трампа) для озвучки текста?

Answer (score 3):

Увы, нет. Сам pyttsx3 использует УЖЕ установленные голоса. В зависмости от вашей ОС это eSpeak, голоса от Microsoft и тд. Использовать он может только их. А в них, насколько мне известно, таких функций нет.